# How can I remove all my searches from the new Activity Log in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, privacy

This is a new feature, inside the activity log. In the past you couldn't view your searches.

As far as I know, the only way to remove a search from the activity log is [manually removing each search](https://www.facebook.com/help/382661798450396/).

I know no one else can see my private activity log, which contains my past searches - I can only view them by checking the "Include Only Me activity" box:

[image]

but since I log in to my account on a shared computer and sometimes leave Facebook open, I am afraid someone will be able to see my past searches.

I have to find a way to delete all of my searches in the activity log. Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `facebook.com/{your username goes here}/allactivity` → click on **MORE** just under Photos & Likes, on the left side column → click on **Search** → click on **Clear Searches** on top.

Comment: Thank you. I would also want to clear my searches on Facebook's databases, so that when searching, a person that I visit his profile more often, won't show up first - but I guess that's impossible.